# user input in R (Rscript and Widows command prompt)

Tags: r, cmd, user-input, readline, rscript

I am trying to figure out, how can i run an  r script, using `Rscript` in windows command prompt and ask for user input.

So far, i have found answers on how do ask for user input in R's interactive shell. Any effort in doing the same with  `readline()` or `scan()` has failed.

example:

I have a polynomial `y=cX` where `X` can take more than one values `X1`,`X2`,`X3` and so on. `C` variable is know,  so what i need in order to calculate the value of `y` is to ask the user for the `Xi` values and store them somewhere inside my script.

```
Uinput <- function() {
    message(prompt"Enter X1 value here: ")
    x <- readLines()
}
```

Is this the way to go? Any additional arguments? Will `as.numeric` help? How do i return `X1`? And will the implementation differ depending on the OS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That's the general way to go, but the implementation needs some work: you don't want readLines, you want readline (yes, the name is similar. Yes, this is dumb. R is filled with silly things ;).

What you want is something like:

```
UIinput <- function(){

    #Ask for user input
    x <- readline(prompt = "Enter X1 value: ")

    #Return
    return(x)
}
```

You probably want to do some error-handling there, though (I could provide an X1 value of FALSE, or "turnip"), and some type conversion, since readline returns a one-entry character vector: any numeric input provided should probably be converted to, well, a numeric input. So a nice, user-proof way of doing this might be...

```
UIinput <- function(){

    #Ask for user input
    x <- readline(prompt = "Enter X1 value: ")

    #Can it be converted?
    x <- as.numeric(x)

    #If it can't, be have a problem
    if(is.na(x)){

         stop("The X1 value provided is not valid. Please provide a number.")

    }

    #If it can be, return - you could turn the if into an if/else to make it more
    #readable, but it wouldn't make a difference in functionality since stop()
    #means that if the if-condition is met, return(x) will never actually be
    #evaluated.
    return(x)
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that even though code seems to run smoothly and without errors, nothing happens in terminal. Literally nothing..

Comment: That's...strange. I assume you're actually calling the function?

Comment: Alright i found the answer i was looking for elsewhere. Thanks for the effort nonetheless

Comment: @KapelNick don't leave us hanging - how did you resolve it? :).

Comment: `cat("blablabla: ")
x <- readLines(con="stdin", 1)
x <- as.numeric(x)` worked for me

Comment: That'd work, but I'm confused as to why the above solution didn't. How were you running it?

Comment: Well i did try several variations of the code without any success. Did it work for you? I might be going trying to implement it again in the future and see why it didn't work. For the time being my schedule is tight.

Comment: I believe the solution user347128 works if you put curly brackets around the calls: `{
username <- UIinput()
password <-UIinput()
}`

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me running a Rscript via Rscript.exe in a batch file (.bat).
As someone wrote it this worked for me as well :

```r
cat("blablabla: ")
x <- readLines(con="stdin", 1)
x <- as.numeric(x)
```