# R language, pause loop and ask user for continue

Tags: r, loops, pause

i have an idea to pause loop at some iteration and ask "user" for some answer.

for example

```
some_value = 0
some_criteria = 50
for(i in 1:100)
{
  some_value = some_value + i
  if(some_value > some_criteria)
  {
    #Here i need to inform the user that some_value reached some_criteria
    #I also need to ask the user whether s/he wants to continue operations until the loop ends
    #or even set new criteria
  }
}
```

Again, I want to pause loop, and ask user if he would like to continue like: "Press Y/N"

Comment: Related [How to wait for a keypress in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272916/how-to-wait-for-a-keypress-in-r) and [user input in R (Rscript and Widows command prompt)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895370/user-input-in-r-rscript-and-widows-command-prompt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
some_value = 0
some_criteria = 50
continue = FALSE
for(i in 1:100){
  some_value = some_value + i
  print(some_value)
  if(some_value > some_criteria && continue == FALSE){
    #Here i need to infrom user, that some_value reached some_criteria
    print(paste('some_value reached', some_criteria))

    #I also need to ask user whether he wants co countinue operations until loop ends
    #or even set new criteria

    question1 <- readline("Would you like to proceed untill the loop ends? (Y/N)")
    if(regexpr(question1, 'y', ignore.case = TRUE) == 1){
      continue = TRUE
      next
    } else if (regexpr(question1, 'n', ignore.case = TRUE) == 1){
      question2 <- readline("Would you like to set another criteria? (Y/N)")
      if(regexpr(question2, 'y', ignore.case = TRUE) == 1){
        some_criteria <-  readline("Enter the new criteria:")
        continue = FALSE
      } else {
        break  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can often appear more visible and more user friendly to use pop-up message dialogues for this kind of thing.  Below I use `tkmessageBox` from tcltk2 package for this.  In this example I used `break` to exit your loop once the condition is met.  Depending on your specific use case, it is sometimes preferable to use `while` loops in this type of situation rather than having to break out of a `for` loop prematurely.

```
library(tcltk2)
some_value = 0
some_criteria = 50
continue = TRUE
for(i in 1:100) { 
  some_value = some_value + i
  if(some_value > some_criteria) {
    response <- tkmessageBox(
      message = paste0('some_value > ', some_criteria, '. Continue?'), 
      icon="question", 
      type = "yesno", 
      default = "yes")
    if (as.character(response)[1]=="no") continue = FALSE
  }
  if (!continue) break()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Paulo MiraMor's response if you had multiple some_criteria options (like I did when I found this)

```
regexpr(question1, 'y', ignore.case = TRUE) == 1
```

could be replaced with

```
question1 %in% list_of_criteria_conditions
```

where list_of_criteria_conditions can be something like

```
list_of_criteria_conditions <- c("criteria_1", 1, TRUE)
```